# http handlers and modules for WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I realize that handlers and modules are part of the asp.net lifecycle so my question is, is there an equivalent to handlers or modules that can be applied to WCF or ASMX?

The goal is to quickly apply an unhandled error logging module to each of our asp.net sites as well as services without rebuilding them. I was able to build a module for the asp.net sites and easily add it in with a single config change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASMX being a deprecated technology I prefer not talk about it, let's leave it die peacefully and as quickly as possible.

As far as WCF is concerned the best way to handle errors is by implementing a custom [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) and wrap any unmanaged exceptions that might have propagated from operation contracts into fault contracts.

Comment: @DustinDavis, not necessarily, you could develop the error handler in a separate class library and then inject it into the app/web.config (depending on where your service is hosted).

Comment: I realized I could add it as a custom behavior in config after i made that comment.

Comment: So what about ASMX? I still have to support them even though they are deprecated.

Comment: @DustinDavis, for ASMX you have HTTP modules, Application_Error, ... Just make sure that unhabdled exceptions are caught and wrapped in SoapException. Me too I have to support old ASMX services and the way I support them is by writing WCF wrappers around them.